# Boost.spirit code. Compiler error

Tags: c++, boost, stl, compiler-errors, boost-spirit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main ()
{
    std::string input("aa aa aa");
    std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();

    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), qi::ascii::space_type > testRule = 
        +(qi::string("aa"));

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(strbegin, input.end(),
            testRule,
            qi::space,                  
            result);                               

    if (ok && strbegin == input.end()) {
        std::cout << result.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << result[i] << " ";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::string(strbegin, input.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I need help to find out problem in this code. The error message is:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal.hpp:14:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::spirit::locals<> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, T1 = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >(), T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/reference.hpp:43:71:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::reference<Subject>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::spirit::locals<> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, Subject = const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:164:9:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Expr = boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l> >, Skipper = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, Attr = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:197:86:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Expr = boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l> >, Skipper = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, Attr = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]’
main.cpp:20:19:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:303:17: error: no match for call to ‘(const function_type {aka const boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >&)>}) (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l> >::context_type&, const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1048:7: note: candidate is:
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:761:17: note: boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::result_type boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::operator()(T0, T1, T2, T3) const [with R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >&, boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::result_type = bool]
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:761:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >’ to ‘const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >&’
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of `qi::space` is `qi::space_type`. So remove the `ascii` or have it on both.